# Docker container exits with "context cancelled" when I try to build (Windows 11)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

**UPDATE:** The issue seemed to be caused by a few files in my project directory that somehow got stuck in the process of being backed up to OneDrive. Whatever Windows was trying to do to them was preventing Docker from properly accessing them, so by manually canceling the upload (and in some cases just deleting the offending files) I was able to make it work.

I have a Docker container that was having some problems, so I decided to update Docker in case the old version I was using was the source of the issue. However, upon updating to the latest version of Docker (4.23.0) the container does not build at all. The build process gets up to the first line of the Dockerfile, at which point I get the message `=> CANCELED [web internal] load build context` and the process exits with the following error:

```
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

Is there anything else I can do here, or should I just try to downgrade my version of Docker? Here's the full Dockerfile, if that's of any use:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 python:3.9-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY pip.conf /root/.pip/pip.conf
WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN ls -l

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
  && apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev \
  && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client \
  && pip install pyodbc \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip install cryptography --no-cache-dir
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

COPY . /code/
RUN chmod u+x /code/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod u+x /code/wait-for-it.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/code/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Here's the console output from the failed build:

```
[+] Building 3.8s (7/20)                                                                                              docker:default 
 => [web internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                        0.1s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 939B                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [web internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                           0.1s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                 0.0s 
 => [web] resolve image config for docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1                                                                1.4s 
 => CACHED [web] docker-image://docker.io/docker/dockerfile:1@sha256:ac85f380a63b13dfcefa89046420e1781752bab202122f8f50032edf3  0.0s 
 => [web internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-buster                                                        0.7s 
 => CACHED [web  1/14] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-buster@sha256:bae5b428ebf32d01a902718b0a58874cbf33d7a4b6a65b7cd7b21d4  0.0s 
 => CANCELED [web internal] load build context                                                                                  0.9s 
 => => transferring context: 4.93MB                                                                                             0.8s 
failed to solve: Canceled: context canceled
```

Answer (score 0):

Metered connections in Windows 10 and Windows 11 sometimes lead to problems with Docker, respectively, docker pulling images, which seems to be the problem here. Try to disable all of your [metered connections](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/metered-connections-in-windows-7b33928f-a144-b265-97b6-f2e95a87c408) and see if the container builds.

It would also be interesting to see if you can pull the image with
`docker pull python:3.9-buster`.

Comment: On Win11, at least, metered connections seem to be disabled by default. I did check the WiFi network I was using when I encountered this problem, but it doesn't have a metered connection available. 
Running the pull command you provided gave me a bunch of "already exists" lines, and no errors, but trying to build afterwards still failed.

Comment: @Enderhippo Any progress on solving the issue?

Comment: It seems like the issue was caused by some random files in the project directory that somehow got stuck in the OneDrive upload process, and so Docker couldn't properly access them. I just manually cancelled the upload and it works now.